# How to write custom / own plugin for ionic framework

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

Im trying to write own plugin to call native iOS functions. Can any one guide me in writing own plugin & consume it to my ionic application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using **Cordova's Plugin Development Guide.**
from docs it says,

> Plugins comprise a single JavaScript interface along with
>   corresponding native code libraries for each supported platform. In
>   essence this hides the various native code implementations behind a
>   common JavaScript interface.

you can check these articles for kick-start.

**[Plugin Development Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/)**

**[How to write Cordova Plugins](https://medium.com/ionic-and-the-mobile-web/how-to-write-cordova-plugins-864e40025f2)**

**[Tutorial](http://moduscreate.com/writing-a-cordova-plugin-in-swift-for-ios/)**

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot for your guidance, I have created the plugin, but when i installed the plugin i don't no how to import to my ionic code. Can you guide me in that.  Thanks in advance...

Comment: [installing](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/#validating-a-plugin-using-plugman) may be this can help.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, I have followed the same steps & even i have created the plugin & installed but for some reasons, I cant able to import to my ionic project even i tried to add this jumio plugin (https://github.com/payfriendz/cordova-plugin-jumio), When i tried to follow the steps it shows me the error. Please guide me in using this plugin. it will solve my other issues too. thanks in advance.